# Footable does not show Font Aweseome icons/Glyphicons?

Tags: font-awesome, footable

I have create a table and added the latest version of Footable which work fine. When adding Font Awesome icons to an item(td) nothing is happening, it is not accepting the code either way I inject it in:

HTML:

```html
<td>A-kasse HK <i class="fa fa-check" aria-hidden="true"></i></td>
```

Using css:

```css
.icon {
    position: relative;

    .accepted:before {
        content: '\25AE';
        font-family: FontAwesome;
        left:-5px;
        position:absolute;
        top:0;
    }
  }
```

So far removing the footable initiation script will display the Font Awesome icons, but that is not a great solution. I can include the icons anywhere else on the page, just not in the table.

Anyone have come across this problem?

Answer (score 0):

The solution suggested [here](https://github.com/fooplugins/FooTable/issues/190) is to edit the css file and replace all the font-specific code with your font-awesome or similar CSS. The file to look at is : https://github.com/bradvin/FooTable/blob/V2/css/footable.core.css

*(Sry, basically the link would have answered it, but as that is not accepted, I included the entire post...)*